# How can I read files created by Samsung Recovery Backup solution?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-backup

I did a backup of my laptop with Samsung Recovery Backup solution and installed Windows 7. Because I needed the space that was ocupied by all files I copied them to my external drive.

What I want now is to be able to read all information from that backup. I have got pictures of my wedding and honeymoon there. If I don't find a solution I'll lose them.

Comment: When you did it, did you perform a "Complete Backup" or "Data Backup"?

Comment: data backup I think I am not sure cause I did while ago

Answer (score 2):

[You should be able to use the same software that created the backup to restore it](http://ars.samsung.com/customer/usa/jsp/faqs/faqs_view_us.jsp?SITE_ID=1&PG_ID=1&PROD_SUB_ID=1352&PROD_ID=0&AT_ID=357463)

.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly whats the backup solution that Samsung REcovery uses, however, as the most of systems that I already work, backups are usually written using Microsoft Imagex solution. You can verify if Samsung uses it if your backup files extension is ".wim". If its your case, than you can remount it using "imagex" tool. More information about it you will find [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744531%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I will check the extension cause I dont have the drive here with me, thank u